# Why doesn't my React-Django app detect static files?

Tags: django, reactjs, rest, django-rest-framework

I have created a working React + Django REST project and it works fine on my development machine. I have used the following method to make it work on my CentOS 7 server.

1. I created the build directory using `npm run build` and copied that to the Django project root folder.
2. I added the `build` directory on TEMPLATES list in Django settings to identify the `index.html` file.
3. I added `build/static` folder in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.
4. I added `url(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),` line to the root `URLS` file to capture all url patterns and load the index file in build folder that contains the React app.
5. I run `manage.py collectstatic` to create a `staticfiles` folder with all static files.
6. I added the `staticfiles` folder to the Nginx conf file like following:

   `location /static/ {
       root /home/michel/project/staticfiles;
   }`
7. I have restarted the nginx server.

I am using the Django server to load the `index.html` file and I expect that the `staticfiles` folder will contain necessary static files to load my React app.

However, when I visit www.mydomain.com it loads the `index.html` file, but does NOT load the React app on `<div id='root'></div>`. I know this because the footer of the index is shown, but the css for styling that footer is also not working.

I am guessing that I have a problem of making the static files being detected. Any solution?

**EDIT**
Here is the code that links my React app to the index.html file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

P.S. It is automatically generated by the `create-react-app` command.

Comment: post the code of TemplateView and index.html header

Comment: @DmitriiG. The TemplateView is just that one line I use on urls file. That loads the index file. I have updated the question with the index file `<head>` tag and codes contained within it.

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to me. Where is the code where you load the react app?

Comment: I used `create-react-app` to create my frontend. So the default code to load the app onto a div with id `root` is used to load my app to that div. Mind it, when I run the server with `gunicorn bind ...` for checking Gunicorn, the app works perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you actually need help? I've asked you two times already to post the code where you link your react javascript application code into your index.html file with django static filepaths

Comment: @DmitriiG. I have added the code for the linking part. And django static file path is `project_root/staticfiles`.

Comment: Let's go the other way around. You have your html code and you have your javascript code. In order to load js code into html you create a link like <script src='index.js'/>. By 'with django static filepaths' I was expecting to see something along the lines: <script src="{% static 'js/index.js' %}"/>. Do you have that in your template index.html file?

Comment: @DmitriiG. I don't have anything like that on my index.html file but my app works on local machine.

Comment: I have followed https://medium.com/@nicholaskajoh/heres-a-dead-simple-react-django-setup-for-your-next-project-c0b0036663c6 this blog. Maybe you'll know what kind of setup I am using. I followed it as it is and I didn't have to include my JS in my HTML. Maybe it has something to do with setting up my server.

Comment: Alright. Can you post the screenshot/(error log) of browser console when you access your server?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in `main.8d3ebb35.js:1`. This is shown in Chrome console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its probably because you don't understand the Nginx `root` directive.

This:

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/michel/project/staticfiles;
}
```

Means if I request `www.yourwebsite.com/static/style.css` then Nginx is going to expect that file location to be

`/home/michel/project/staticfiles/static/style.css`
not

`/home/michel/project/staticfiles/style.css`

Comment: I will try to move all my static files from `staticfiles` to `static` folder and get back. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. I've solved my problem. However, I have one more question. I've always made `staticfiles` my folder for collectstatic to 'collect' all static files and I don't want to change that to work with React. Is there a way that I can make Nginx read static files from a folder of my choosing instead of `static` by default?

Comment: oh so there was his problem :). @MiniGunnR just write the path you want in nginx config: location /staticfiles {
    root /home/michel/project;
}

Comment: Or change `root /home/michel/project/staticfiles` to `alias /home/michel/project/staticfiles`

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it.